# Merging duplicate rows that have one different value

Tags: mysql

This is an correction of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599896/sql-merge-duplicate-rows-and-join-values-that-are-different) now I properly understand what I need to do.

I have a table with films and the dates they were shown on along with other info in other columns, in MySQL.

So relevant columns are...

```
FilmID

FilmName

DateShown
```

The dates are stored as Unix timestamps.

I currently have multiple instances of films that were shown on different dates yet all other information is the same.

I need to copy the dates of the duplicate films into a new table matching them up to the film ID. Then I need to remove the duplicate film rows from the original table.

So I have created a new table, Film_Dates with the columns

```
FilmDateID
FilmID
Date
```

Can anyone help with the actual sql to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: is filmid duplicated in these rows as well?

Comment: Sorry only just had a chance to get back to you...no FilmID is not duplicated (I everything is the same except FilmID and the Date field though)

Answer (score 1):

to start with:

```
insert into filmdateid (filmid, `date`)
  select filmid, dateshown 
    from films
```

and that should populate your new table.

```
alter ignore table films
  add unique (filmid)
```

This will enforce uniqueness for filmid, and drop all duplicates, keeping just the one row. If this fails with a 'duplicate entry' error, you will need to run this command, and then try the alter again.

`set session old_alter_table=1`

As it seems mysql is moving away from being able to do it this way.

Lastly, you need to get rid of your dateshown column.

```
alter table films
  drop column dateshown
```

Please make sure you have a backup before you attempt any of this. Always best to be safe.

**since filmid is not duplicated, only filmname, there are some extra steps**

first, create the filmdates table:

```
create table filmdates as
  select filmname, dateshown
    from films;
```

Then add a filmid column:

```
alter table filmdates add column filmid integer;
```

And a unique index on `(filmname, dateshown)`

```
alter ignore table filmdates add unique(filmname, dateshown);
```

Then we add a unique index on `films(filmname)` - since its the only value that really gets duplicated.

```
alter ignore table films add unique(filmname);
```

Now that we're setup, we populate the `filmid` column in the new table, with maching values from the old.

```
update films f 
  inner join filmdates fd
    on f.filmname = fd.filmname
  set fd.filmid = f.filmid;
```

Now we just need to cleanup, and get rid of the redundant columns (`films.dateshown` and `filmdates.filmname`).

```
alter table filmdates drop column filmname;
alter table films drop column dateshown;
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38d52/1)

Comment: Just had a chance to look at this. Thank you for taking the time I will try it tonight...but since FilmId is already unique I can copy the film name to the new table too, remove the duplicates using that and then delete the film name column from the new table. I think that should work!

Comment: ah. filmid being unique already means we have to work only with filmname to detect the duplicates then?

Comment: Yes exactly just the names for the duplicate's

Comment: well that changes things a little. i've updated the answer with a plan that better suits your updated requirements